# Where does Spinoza prove the equation ‚God = Nature‘?

Tags: spinoza

In his answer to [Is the God of Spinoza a conscious being?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91378/is-the-god-of-spinoza-a-conscious-being)
@armand refers to Spinoza’s equation

> Deus sive natura (God, i.e. nature)

Indeed, Spinoza equates both terms several times in his work 'Ethics'. He defines his use of the term ‚God‘ (Book I, Def. 6) and then adds some axioms and proves some propositions about God.

But

- where does Spinoza **define** his use of the term ‚nature‘,
- and where does he **prove**    ‚God = Nature‘?

**Added**: Due to the answers resp. comments I am convinced now that Spinoza does **not** define the term 'nature'.

Comment: The expression is explicitly stated into Preface to Part IV (checked with English transl in Wiki)

Comment: Yes, wikipedia enumerates four passages with such an equation. But without further elaboration they are rather worthless to serve as any argument. - Cf. also the answer of @armand.

Comment: And Coroll to I.XXIV.

Comment: Apparently one has to read the primary source, not the tertiary alone :-) - But where in the primary source does Spinoza define (!) 'natura' and where does he prove (!) 'deus sive natura'?

Comment: *natura* is used many times, starting from first definition, but with two different meaning: both undefined. The first one is a synonym of *essence*: **Def.I** Per causam sui intelligo id cujus essentia involvit existentiam sive id cujus *natura* non potest concipi nisi existens. **Prop.I** Substance is by *nature* prior to its modifications. See also "the nature of God", the "nature of the triangle".

Comment: The second usage is in **Prop.VIII.Sch.II**: "res naturales" (*natural objects*) and "quæ ostendunt in rerum natura" (*a given number of individual things exist in nature*). This is the "usual meaning" of *nature* as *universe*, maybe not in the "physical" sense but in the ontological one.

Comment: The key-point is **Prop.XXIX**: Nothing in the universe is contingent, but all things are conditioned to exist and operate in a particular manner by the necessity of the divine nature. Here the two concepts are linked: the *universe* (nature-2) and the divine nature (nature-1). Maybe the English translation shows a "fear" of ambiguity, because the Latin text has: "In *rerum natura* nullum datur contingens sed omnia ex necessitate *divinæ naturæ* determinata sunt ad certo modo existendum et operandum."

Comment: The "*Note*.—Before going any further, I wish here to explain, what we should understand by nature viewed as active (*natura naturans*), and nature viewed as passive (*natura naturata*). I say to explain, or rather call attention to it, for I think that, from what has been said, it is sufficiently clear, that by nature viewed as active we should understand that which is in itself, and is conceived through itself, or those attributes of substance, which express eternal and infinite essence, 1/2

Comment: in other words (Prop. xiv., Coroll. i., and Prop. xvii., Coroll. ii) *God*, in so far as he is considered as a free cause." 2/2

Comment: So, in conclusion, we may agree that there is no def of *nature* but IMO the "equation" is clearly stated.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza OK, let’s take ‚natura‘ in the standard meaning: the set of all things and interactions around. Then Prop. XIV reduces the proof of „deus = natura“ to show that ‚natura‘ is a substance in the sense of Def. 3. Do you see where Spinoza proves the latter? - According to science, considering nature a substance in the sense of Def. 3 is a useful heuristics. Following it, science made great progress. But IMO it’s open how far we can get with it from a prinipal point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He does not demonstrate the equivalence.

In the beginning of the first book he defines god as an infinite being, and demonstrate that god contains everything that exists, is unique, etc.

The expression "Deus sive Natura" is used in the book 4, but no further demonstration is given. It's more like "here is another word commonly used to speak about this concept".

Comment: I agree with your answer. I do not find in Spinoza’s book neither the definition of ‚natura‘ nor a proof of the equation ‚God sive natura‘. – For me this result seems a bit strange for a book which claims to be ‚ordine geometrico demonstrata‘. - If this negative result is actually the last word on the issue, Spinoza may eliminate the term ‚natura‘. Because then by definition ‚natura‘ has the same meaning as ‚god‘, which brings no new insight. Spinoza may go on with ‚res‘ which he uses in so many places in book I. - How do the apologists of Spinoza retort? :-)

Comment: @JoWehler i dont think he needs to demonstrate anything, it's just semantics. And the usage of the word "Natura" is consistent with other philosophers of his time (afaik). Usage of the word "Deus" seems much more misleading to me, considering how it conflicts with the personal, willing and affect driven god described in the scripture. Many contemporates accused Sinoza of atheism for this. After all, if God is the universe and won't answer prayers, why not just call it the universe and stop praying?

Comment: I agree, of course the term 'god' is the prototype of a problematic term. But Spinoza defines his use of the term in Def. 6 which I consider OK for an axiomatic theory.